# Geometry of a Circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Four Tangent circles are centered on the x-axis. The radius of circle A is twice the radius of circle O. The radius of circle C is four times the radius of circle O. All circles have integer radii and the point (63,16) is on the circle. What is the equation of circle A?[The questionnaire is here on the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlVED.png)

Comment: The question is badly written.  Presumably you are to assume $O$ is centered at the origin and the point $(63,16)$ is on circle $C$.  Neither of these is given.

Answer (score 1):

The circle $O$ has radius $r$, centered at 0.
The circle $A$ has radius $2r$, centered at $r+2r=3r$.
The circle $B$ has radius $3r$, centered at $3r+2r+3r=8r$.
The circle $C$ has radius $4r$, centered at $8r+3r+4r=15r$.
The equation of circle $C$ is then
$$(63-15r)^2+16^2=16r^2$$
or
$$209r^2-1890r+4225=0$$
Only one solution is integer, $r=5$. Then the radius of the circle $A$ is 10, and the equation is $$(x-15)^2+y^2=100$$

Answer (score 0):

If the circle $O$ is centered at the origin with radius $r$, the center of $C$ is $(41r,0)$ and its radius is $24r$, so you need $(63-41r)^2+16^2=(24r)^2$  This is a quadratic, but the [solution are a mess](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(63-41r)%5E2%2B16%5E2%3D(24r)%5E2).  We get $r=\frac {2583 \pm8 \sqrt{31301}}{1105}$ with $A$ centered at $(3r,0)$ and having equation $(x-3r)^2+y^2=4r^2$.Both solutions appear acceptable.